# Why does a mongodb replica set require an odd number of voting nodes?

Tags: mongodb

The mongodb documentation suggests that a replica set should have an odd number of voting nodes. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let's imagine that a replica set has even number of nodes (4, for example). Then an unfortunate network partition happens that splits the set in half (2 + 2). Which partition should accept writes? First? Second? Both? What should happen when network is restored? These are all hard questions.

Having odd number of nodes eliminates the questions entirely. The set can't be split exactly in half. So the bigger part will accept writes (to be exact, node must see more than half of nodes (including self) to be elected as primary. So it's 1 of 1, 2 of 3, 3 of 5, 4 of 7 and so on).

Comment: Correct - MongoDB voting works on the concept of quorum http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quorum_(distributed_computing)

Comment: By the way this is called split-brain. Search for it if you need more info.

Comment: Let me admit my ignorance and ask the naive question... If only one node goes down in an odd numbered replica set, than you have the 'even number of nodes' problem.  It would seem like the probability of one node going down would be greater than the probability of two nodes going down.  So why wouldn't you want an even number of nodes to guard against the event that has the greater probability?

Comment: @JohnC: one node going down is not a problem at all. The other nodes still form the majority and can perform elections, etc. Odd number of nodes requirement is to protect from network **partitions** when the cluster is split in half. If it contained even number of nodes, then majority can't be formed (as explained in the answer).

Comment: Thanks Sergio, makes sense..  Another naive question... If a network partition split does occur and the 'incumbent' primary node is alive but on the minority side of the split, I presume that the node will discontinue its primary node role?

Comment: @JohnC: correct. The majority will reelect the new primary.

Comment: I was still confused and after further research I gained a better understanding by thinking about "majority" as relative to total number of nodes, versus total number of remaining nodes.

Comment: @wayofthefuture: yep, it's majority of all nodes, of course.

Comment: @wayofthefuture i am still confused, let's say we have 3 node in the starting, 1 goes down or connectivity fail. we are left with 2 nodes as majority, they will try to decide master, but if both of them elect themselves or others, how do we get away from this deadloack?

Comment: @bestwishes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_algorithm. And also https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/replication-election-and-consensus-algorithm-refinements-for-mongodb-3-2